# gspread delete a range of cells (up)

Tags: python, gspread

Using the GSpread package for Python, how would I use a batch_update to delete a range of cells upwards?

Example code:

```
        sheet_id = self.worksheet.gs_worksheet._properties['sheetId']
        start_index_col = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].col - 1
        end_index_col = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][-1].col - 1
        start_index_row = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].row
        end_index_row = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].row

        self.worksheet.gs_worksheet.batch_update({
            'requests': [
                {
                    'deleteRangeRequest': {
                        'range': {
                            'sheetId': sheet_id,
                            'startRowIndex': start_index_row,
                            'endRowIndex': end_index_row,
                            'startColumnIndex': start_index_col,
                            'endColumnIndex': end_index_col,
                        },
                        'shiftDimension': 'ROWS',
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
```

Response:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 559, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1166, in batch_update
    for vr in data
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1166, in <listcomp>
    for vr in data
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed the syntax on the request, it went through but did nothing.  Command needed to be "deleteRange".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete range using `deleteRangeRequest` of the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" in Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

#### Modification points:

- At gspread, it seems that `batch_update(body)` is the method of class `gspread.models.Spreadsheet`. In your script, I thought that you might use it as the method of class `gspread.models.Worksheet`. I think that this is the reason of the error message of `string indices must be integers`.

  - `batch_update(data, **kwargs)` of class `gspread.models.Worksheet` is the method of "spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate".
- When the DeleteRangeRequest is used in the "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" method, please use it as `deleteRange`.

When above point is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows. Unfortunately, from your script, I couldn't understand about the variable of `self.worksheet.gs_worksheet`. So in this modification, I use other variable name.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet Id.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet_id = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']

start_index_col = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].col - 1
end_index_col = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][-1].col - 1
start_index_row = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].row
end_index_row = self.cell_data_by_row_col[0][0].row

spreadsheet.batch_update({
    'requests': [
        {
            'deleteRange': {
                'range': {
                    'sheetId': sheet_id,
                    'startRowIndex': start_index_row,
                    'endRowIndex': end_index_row,
                    'startColumnIndex': start_index_col,
                    'endColumnIndex': end_index_col,
                },
                'shiftDimension': 'ROWS',
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deleterangerequest)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer.  The batch request went through, but nothing updated, no error just nothing in the response as far as updates.

Comment: @Carl Von Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, when `res` of `res = spreadsheet.batch_update({,,,})` is checked, what value will you obtain? And/or, for example, when `start_index_col, end_index_col, start_index_row, end_index_row` are `0, 1, 0, 1`, respectively, only cell "A1" is deleted?